# How to define dynamic variables in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner with `VBA` Excel and I'm trying to do an application for my thesis, that has to manipulate excel files during the process.

I will basically have a workbook composed by many worksheets, and I want to save effectively some data, using only one FOR to save some time. The problem is that I don't know which are going to be the names of the worksheets imported (already done this importation part).

So, I want to save the columns where I found some data (strings 'Create' and 'Delete'), but I can't assign them to a static variable, because they'll be overwritten. So my idea was to put them on dynamic variables, according to the name of the sheet, but I don't know how to do that.

My first try was the following, but the code doesn't work... `ws.Name & c = w` and `ws.Name & d = w` are giving error.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> concepts Then
         For w = 1 To ws.Name.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             If ws.Name.Cells(1, w).Value = create Then
                 ws.Name & "c" = w
             ElseIf ws.Name.Cells(1, w).Value = delete Then
                 ws.Name & "d" = w
             End If
         Next w
    EndIf
Next
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: FYI, as you have it, `create`  and `delete` are variables. If you're trying to see if the value is the strings, then you need to wrap those in quotes, e.g. `... = "create"`, or `... = "delete"`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, those strings are already assigned to those variables... var create = "Create" and var delete = "Delete"

Comment: That's not the problem here  :)

Comment: Are all the values unique? If so you could use a `Collection` or `Dictionary` of values

Comment: @Tom, that would be hard for this purpose I think... Isn't there any way I can assign a value (in this case the column = Long) to something like this:  "Namex" & "1" ?

Comment: Because that "Namex" will vary with the worksheet, and that way I can always know what's assign to it... This would be the perfect solution, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Using dynamic variables in `VBA` would be a lot more complex. You would need to Trust access to the VBA project object model to be able to create vba code on the fly. `VBA` won't allow you to create dynamic variables like some other languages. You'd have to programatically write the code before executing it.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're wondering if you can indirectly create and reference variables. i.e. in the loop, assign a value to a variable named "Name1c" (sheet name = "Name1") or a variable named "Name1d", etc for each sheet. @Tom is right. There isn't a simple solution using dynamic variables. However, it sounds like for the dynamic variables to work, you're already assuming that the sheet names are unique. From your existing code, I do believe either a dictionary or collection may be the easiest solution.

Comment: @tom: I know exactly what you [MEAN](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2019/03/22/create-a-new-variable-object-at-runtime/) :P

Comment: Also, if the dynamic variable idea had worked, with the way the code is set up, at the end of the `For`-loop each of the variables would only have a single value. If there is more than one create or destroy per sheet, the code would only save the `w` value for the last one.

Comment: @SiddharthRout haha thanks - that's exactly what I meant :P

Comment: Oh... I thought this would be easier to do, since it looks so simple. And using a `Collection`, would I have do create one for each worksheet? Or use one with all the columns values saved?

Comment: Or something like this would work? ´With collectionx
    .Value = ws.Name  & "c"
End With´

Comment: @Mistella, but there's only one value per create and per delete, that's why I though about this solution!  :)

Comment: Also, some sources I have found helpful for [collections](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/) and [dictionaries](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using a dictionary

```
Dim dict As Object
Dim dictKey As String

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> concepts Then
        For w = 1 To ws.Name.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If ws.Name.Cells(1, w).Value = Create Then
                dictKey = ws.Name & c
            ElseIf ws.Name.Cells(1, w).Value = Delete Then
                dictKey = ws.Name & d
            End If

            If Not dict.exists(dictKey) Then
                dict.Add dictKey, w
            Else
                MsgBox dictKey & " already exists"
            End If
         Next w
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Further explanation: This will only keep the first instance of each create/delete in a worksheet. If the last is desired, the existing value could be replaced with the newest found.

Comment: Tip: reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library, then you can declare `dict As Dictionary`, do `Set dict = New Dictionary`, and get intellisense & autocompletion as you type. Every single Windows box built this century has the same version of that library, there's no reason to systematically late-bind it.

Comment: @Mistella, and to get the values from the dictKeys i just have to do ´x = dict("Namec") right?

Comment: @FranciscaParenteCambra exactly

Comment: Just one more thing @Mistella, the ´If Not´ is adding the value of w to the respective dictKey, but only if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary? Is not it the other way around?

Comment: Or @Tom, if you know the answer pls

Comment: @FranciscaParenteCambra `dict.exists(dictKey)` returns True if `dictKey` is an existing key in the dictionary, False if it isn't. Therefore, `Not dict.exists(dictKey)` is equal to True if the dictionary does not have any keys matching `dictKey`. The reason for the `If statement` is because trying to `Add` a key that already exists causes an error; all keys are required to be unique. A dictionary is initially blank - no keys, no values. Information is always added in pairs: key and value. However, if a key already exists, the value can still be updated/edited.